# how to get Instagram ads data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to implement a service that will pull Facebook and Instagram ads data using Facebook marketing API. We ran the ads on Facebook from the Facebook ads manager and I am able to pull facebook ads data. On Instagram, we boosted a post from the mobile app and all the insights are available on the app itself. I am not able to find that ad on Facebook ads manager or any other web portal. When I try to get campaigns, ad sets, and ads from API all I am getting is Facebook ads data.

Question 1: Where can I see the Instagram ad data on the web portal(Facebook ads manager or something similar)?
Question 2: Do I need to connect the account on Facebook and Instagram from somewhere else too? I already connected the Instagram page to the Facebook page and I have admin access on both.

If you have any other suggestions please do tell me.